# Locale switching using ptrthomas/karate-chrome

Tags: google-chrome, karate

Is it possible to set chrome default locale programmatically when choosing the webdriver ?
Right now I have 3 different docker images (FR, ES, EN) but it makes my gitlab runners run very slowly (or looks like it is) and also it is also not very flexible to test locally.
Is there a way to switch chrome locale on the fly inbetween tests ?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I think the locale is hard-coded in the Docker container as of now. Do you think you can contribute code so that it can be parameterized.

The relevant Docker file is here: https://github.com/intuit/karate/blob/master/karate-docker/karate-chrome/Dockerfile

Comment: Hi Peter, thanks for your answer. Not sure I will have the opportuniy to contribute. but I'll see what I can do. Thanks